# How can I prevent some hotkeys from being redirected to the remote PC with VMWare Horizon Client?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop, vmware, hotkeys, focus

I'm using VMWare Horizon Client to connect to several PCs at work. I like to have them fullscreen and I keep each connection on its own virtual desktop. I'd like to be able to use the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>LEFT</kbd>/<kbd>RIGHT</kbd> key combination to switch between them but the key combination is forwarded to the remote PC.

When using RDP I can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>HOME</kbd> to give keyboard focus back to the local PC but the horizon client knows not of such arcane magic (at least to the best of my googling abilities).

I actually found [somewhere in their documentation](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Horizon-Client-for-Windows/5.3/horizon-client-windows-installation/GUID-81B739A0-51BA-4BFF-AA26-90BEAD0AEC0D.html) that I could somehow use group policy editor to configure `Hotkey combination to release input focus` but this requires downloading an administrative template from VMWare which plebs such as myself aren't entitled to do. Also, the admin here apparently has no idea what anything on that documentation page means and he can't download the file either.

Comment: I don't know VMWare specifically, but I've found it to be easier in the long run to change your local machine's key command for things that conflict with the remotes, especially if the remotes are operated by humans usually, so it doesn't confuse them.

Comment: With VMWare every command gets sent to the remote PC. Therefore, no matter how I change them this won't work. It'll just send the modified keystrokes to the remote and they won't register locally at all.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is, since the clipboard is shared, I can write a small program which will run on all remote PCs and when this program detects a certain hotkey it would copy something to the clipboard. Then, on the local PC, I would detect this clipboard event and act accordingly... but this is kind of a macgyver overkill way to do it.

Comment: Did you find the answer to your question? I have exactly the same problem

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. I got myself a keyboard that has built in macro support with dedicated macro keys. I assigned two such keys to switch the virtual desktop. Fortunately, the macro command is executed on the host and is not redirected to the VMWare guest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mentioned document (also available as [HTML](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Horizon-Client-for-Windows/2111/horizon-client-windows-installation/GUID-366D5333-B56B-423E-88C1-DC58EFCEE937.html)) lists the default value for "Hotkey combination to release input focus":

> When this setting is disabled or not configured, the user can release
> focus by pressing Ctrl+Alt or clicking outside the remote desktop
> window.

Comment: This doesn't work when using RDP protocol, which is what I am using. However, since I haven't mentioned this in my question, you have technically answered it so I am going to give you the answer. Besides, it's been two years and no one else stepped up.